# "Jolly Jumper" challenge

Tags: c++, windows, stl

I'm a C#/Java full-time developer who is trying to pick up C++ purely for educational reasons. I've tried to solve a pretty simple [ACM ICPC problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=12&page=show_problem&problem=979) and would love to hear all kinds of criticisms on how to write acceptable modern C++ code. (*Seriously, tell me that my code is a joke, as long as you can tell me how to make it better.*)

Specifically, I'd like to hear comments on the following aspects:

1. Does the code follow typical C++ coding convention?
2. Is it cross platform? [Especially regarding how I am handling strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).
3. Is it C++11 compliant? Am I making a reasonable use of it?
4. Is the code **readable?**

You're also welcome to comment on my algorithm on solving the problem, although that's less of a concern for me at the moment because the primary purpose for me is to learn how to properly use C++.

[Full source (VS2012)](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=12&page=show_problem&problem=979)

---

The challenge is to determine whether each line of input contains a "jolly jumper" sequence:

> A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the difference between successive elements take on all the values 1 through n-1. For instance,
>
> > 1 4 2 3
>
> is a jolly jumper, because the absolutes differences are 3, 2, and 1 respectively.

Below is a test input you can try running against the program. The program works as intended as far as I can tell.

> ```
> 4 1 4 2 3
> 5 1 4 2 -1 6
> 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> 10 1 2 4 7 11 16 22 29 37 46
> 10 -1 -2 -4 -7 -11 -16 -22 -29 -37 -46
> 10 -1 -1 -4 -7 -11 -16 -22 -29 -37 -46
> 1 1
> 2 1 2
> 2 2 1
> 4 0 4 2 3
> 4 1 3 2 4
> 1 2
> 6 1 4 3 7 5 10
> ```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__) 
    #define WIN32_DEF 1
#else
    #define WIN32_DEF 0
#endif

#if WIN32_DEF
#include "win32helper.h"
#endif

#include "jolly_jumper.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    #if _DEBUG && WIN32_DEF
        //Visual studio does some wacky things with setting current directory when ran under debug mode..
        //This could be changed in the project settings, but might as well as add code here to
        //manually control current working directory...
        cout << "[Running under debug mode]" << endl;
        setCurrentDirectoryForVSDebug();
    #endif

    string fileName = "";
    if (argc > 1) {
        fileName = string(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Input file name: ";
        getline(cin, fileName); 
    }

    while (fileName.empty()) {
        cout << "Filename cannot be empty!" << endl;
        cout << "Input file name: ";
        getline(cin, fileName); 
    }

    cout << "Reading from: " << fileName << endl;

    ifstream fileStream(fileName);
    if (!fileStream || !fileStream.is_open()) {
        cout << endl << fileName << " could not be opened. Make sure the file exists and the read permission has been set correctly.";
        return 0;
    }

    JollyJumper jollyJumper;
    string currLine = "";
    while (getline(fileStream,currLine)) {
        cout << currLine << endl;   
        if (jollyJumper.IsJolly(currLine)) {
            cout << "Jolly" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not Jolly" << endl;
        }
    }

    fileStream.close();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**string_helper.h**

```
#ifndef __STRING_HELPER_H
#define __STRING_HELPER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

//Static Class Declaration
class StringHelper {
private:
    StringHelper() {};
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> &Split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems);
    static std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string &s, char delim);
    static bool IsNumber(const std::string& s);

};


#endif
```

**jolly_jumper.h**

```
#ifndef __JOLLY_JUMPER_H_ 
#define __JOLLY_JUMPER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

class JollyJumper
{
private:

public:
    JollyJumper();
    bool IsJolly(std::string input);
};

#endif
```

**win32helper.h**

```
#ifndef __WIN32_HELPER_H_
#define __WIN32_HELPER_H_

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <iostream>

void setCurrentDirectoryForVSDebug();

#endif
```

**jolly_jumper.cpp**

```
#include "jolly_jumper.h"
#include "string_helper.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::set;

#define MAX_INPUT_VALUE 2000

JollyJumper::JollyJumper()
{
}

bool JollyJumper::IsJolly(string input)
{
    if (input.empty())
        return false;

    vector<string> elements = StringHelper::Split(input, ' ');
    if (elements.size() == 1)
        return true;

    //First value determines the count of input
    if (!StringHelper::IsNumber(elements.front()))
        return false;

    int inputLength = stoi(elements.front());

    if (inputLength > MAX_INPUT_VALUE)
        return false;

    if (elements.size() - 1 != inputLength)
        return false;

    //Skip first element since it only tells us the size of the elements
    auto it = elements.begin();
    it++;

    //Validate string inputs and make sure they are integers.
    //Once validated, push the difference of curr iterator and next iterator to jolly_diff vector
    set<int> jolly_diff;
    for (; it != elements.end(); it++) {        
        if (!StringHelper::IsNumber(*it)) {
            return false;
        }

        int value = abs(stoi(*it));

        auto nx = std::next(it);
        if (nx == elements.end()) {
            break;
        }

        if (!StringHelper::IsNumber(*nx)) {
            return false;
        }

        int nextValue = abs(stoi(*nx));

        int difference = abs(value - nextValue);

        //Difference cannot logically be greater than the input length
        if (difference >= inputLength)
            return false;

        //Duplicate difference means it is not a jolly jumper
        if(jolly_diff.find(difference) != jolly_diff.end()) {
            return false;
        }
        jolly_diff.insert(difference);
    }

    return true;
}
```

**string_helper.cpp**

```
#include "string_helper.h"

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::getline;
using std::stringstream;

vector<string>& StringHelper::Split(const string &s, char delim, vector<string> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


vector<string> StringHelper::Split(const string &s, char delim) {
    vector<string> elems;
    Split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

bool StringHelper::IsNumber(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    if(s.size() > 1 && (s[0] == '-' || s[0] == '+')) it++;
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

**win32helper.cpp**

```
#include "win32helper.h"

using std::wcout;
using std::endl;

void setCurrentDirectoryForVSDebug() {
        TCHAR currentFilePath[MAX_PATH];
        //Get the full path including the file name from the executable
        GetModuleFileName(NULL, currentFilePath, MAX_PATH);
        //Remove filename and get directory only
        PathRemoveFileSpec(currentFilePath);

        wcout << "Setting current directory to: " << currentFilePath << endl << endl;
        SetCurrentDirectory(currentFilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just focus on your jolly_jumper.h:

> ```
> #ifndef __JOLLY_JUMPER_H_ 
> #define __JOLLY_JUMPER_H_
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> #include <vector>
> #include <set>
>
> class JollyJumper
> {
> private:
>
> public:
>     JollyJumper();
>     bool IsJolly(std::string input);
> };
>
> #endif
> ```

Issues I see include:

- Pay attention to const correctness.  The parameter should be `const`, and the method should be `const`.
- The method is going to be doing too much: it needs to parse the input string as a vector, then run its algorithm.  The `IsJolly()` method should take a vector (as a `const std::vector&`).
- Your class is "degenerate".  There's no state.  Your constructor does nothing.  You might as well write it as a standalone function, or perhaps a class that contains a static function.
- The `private` keyword is just noise.

In summary, I suggest:

```
struct JollyJumper
{
    static bool IsJolly(const std::vector &input);
};
```

Comment: or even:
`namespace JollyJumper`

Answer (score 3):

At first glance the bits that strike me as odd here involve your `StringHelper` class.
Since it is a class with nothing but static members it would probably be better suited as a C++ `namespace`.

A `namespace` gives you essentially the same functionality as a class with nothing but static members, but better stresses your intent. Also, `namespaces` unlike classes can be re-opened and added to in separate modules giving them some versatility.

It also seems strange to me that you have a `Split` method in your `StringHelper` class with this declaration:

```
static std::vector<std::string> &Split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems);
```

It both takes a parameter `elems` which appears to be an output parameter, and it returns a value which in the implementation happens to also be `elems`. I would say that you should either avoid the output parameter and return a `std::vector<std::string>` by value or return `void` and use `elems` the parameter as the sole output of the method. Again this would clarify your intent. Having both a return value and an output parameter suggests that there are two important and different outputs from this function.

Furthermore, it seems that that version of `Split` is merely an implementation detail of the other `Split` declared as:

```
static std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string &s, char delim)
```

Since the first `Split` function appears to be an implementation detail and not used or intended as part of the `StringHelper` public interface, it shouldn't be a public member function. If you leave `StringHelper` as a class, you might make that `Split` a private member. If you make `StringHelper` a `namespace` the non-public version of `Split` would be better as a free function in an unnamed `namespace` in the implementation file (.cpp) for `StringHelper` with no declaration at all in the header file.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @YoungJohn observations:

- `class JollyJumper`

  A class with a single method and no state is just a noise to displease Occam. `IsJolly` should be made free.
- `IsNumber()`

  Seems redundant. `stoi()`, among other things, returns an index of a first unconverted character; to test that the whole string is converted compare it to string length.
- Testing for duplicates.

  A call to `find()` is redundant: `set::insert()` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, where the `second` is `false` when you inserting a duplicate.